# Do I need to call readFileSync() again if I use writeFile() in another js file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs, discord, discord.js

I'm making a discord bot, and I currently have it set up like this:

There's index.js, which handles commands.

If the command is X, it goes to X.js

If the command is Y, it goes to Y.js

I have X.js and Y.js both reading and writing to the same JSON file (in non-conflicting areas) using fs.readFileSync() and fs.writeFile()

fs.readFileSync() is only called once in each X and Y at the startup of the command script.
reading/writing works fine from the same file with that one call, but I haven't testing how it works with multiple scripts writing to the same file with a single call at the beginning.

I assume this isn't going to work?

And, presuming it will not work, what solution would you guys suggest?

Calling fs.readFileSync() in X/Y every time the command X/Y is called (How efficient is this? Right now I don't call commands very often - maybe a couple times an hour at most - but if this ends up going public, there could be quite a few calls of X/Y per second. Would this put a significant strain on the filesystem/bot/etc? I presume not, just making sure!)

Making an outside script to handle reading + writing (X/Y would call on this script for data, and output data to be written.)

Using different files for each script (ahh i really would not like to do this!!)

Maybe another solution? Who knows...

If anyone has done something similar/knows a solution, please don't hesitate to post :)
Thanks!

Comment: if you write to the file in `x.js`, the content is not magically updated in `y.js` for you

Comment: @JaromandaX Yeah.... that's what I figured... I'm mainly looking for the most efficient solution then, I guess

Comment: Some operating systems allow you to watch for changes in a file. Not sure if node has access to this feature

Comment: ah, fs.watch may work. I'll try it out, thanks :)

Comment: yep, that's the one!

Answer (score 0):

What you are wanting to do is called "Hot Reloading". Though hot loading is tricky.

If you require the path to the same file after it's changed the older module will be returned because it will already be in memory, this prevents excessive disk I/O. If you do get to loading the newer module you will also want to clear the old module

---

Instead, I would suggest you use a package like [nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon), which will restart the whole application when a file is changed:

```
# You may need to use sudo on linux/macOS or Administrative 
npm i -g nodemon 

# Restart your Terminal
nodemon ./path/to/your/file.js
```

---

From your description, I assume you are taking user input from and using that to dynamically create a path of the file. This can be a bad idea, because I could use a command like `!../../index.js` and possibly mess up your bot.

To handle I myself use a bit more of a complicated system to handle commands, but this might be a good start.

```
const commands = {};

const modules = load_modules_from_directory();

for ( const module of modules ) {
    commands[ module.name ] = module.function;
}

function messageHandler( message ) {
    if( !is_valid_command( message.content ) )
        return

    const command_string = 
        remove_prefix_and_get_first_word( message.content );

    if ( commands.hasOwnProperty( command_string ) ) 
        commands[ command_string ]( message );
}
```